# IQueryable does not contain definition for GetAwaiter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using WebAPI in entity framework to create a new endpoint and I am having some issues. I'm trying to use a Linq Where statement to get my data, but I'm receiving the following error.

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and
>   no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code.

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Vocab))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetVocabByLesson(int lessonId)
    {
        Vocab vocab = await db.Vocabs.Where(a => a.LessonId == lessonId);
        if (vocab == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(vocab);
    }
```

Comment: Well, why did you expect that to be okay? How do you expect the result of `Where` to be awaitable? And when do you ever expect the result to be `null`? (`Where` returns a sequence - which may be empty, but which is never null...)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`FirstOrDefaultAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220208(v=vs.113).aspx) extension method:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Vocab))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetVocabByLesson(int lessonId)
{
        Vocab vocab = await db.Vocabs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.LessonId == lessonId);
        if (vocab == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(vocab);
}
```

By your code I can deduct you want to return just an element, that's why I have suggested to use `FirstOrDefaultAsync`. But in case you want to get more than one element that meets some condition then use [`ToListAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Vocab))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetVocabByLesson(int lessonId)
{
        var result= await db.Vocabs.Where(a => a.LessonId == lessonId).ToListAsync();
        if (!result.Any())
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: While this works, it only returns one record. Thats why i wanted to use the where statement to return all rows that matched.

Comment: Take a look what I have added to my solution, hope this help you