# Resolve IQueryable and Async in Method

Tags: c#, linq, generics, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to incorporate principle of Async and implement correctly.
In code below, departmentRepository.GetAll returns IQueryable. After that, GetPage(1,3) returns IEnumerable. Just curious if new line of code makes sense according to Intellisense.

**Original Code:**

App Service Code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DepartmentDto>> GetAllDepartments()
{
    var departments = await departmentRepository.GetAll();
    Paged<Department> departmentPaged = new Paged<Department>(departments);
    var departments2 = departmentPaged.GetPage(1, 3);
    var departmentDto = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Department>, IEnumerable<DepartmentDto>>(departments2);
    return  departmentDto;
}
```

First line await departmentRepository.GetAll() is giving me an error.

> IQueryable does not contain definition for GetAwaiter and noaccessible extension method Getawaiter`

So Intellisense recommends change to

```
var departments = await departmentRepository.GetAll().ToListAsync();
```

After changing, then second error pops up in line var departments2 = departmentPaged.GetPage(1, 3);

> Cannot convert to System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Linq.IQueryable.

So Intellisense recommends changing to

```
Paged<Department> departmentPaged = new Paged<Department>(departments.AsQueryable());
```

**So New code looks as follows:**

Does this make sense, is it roundabout, or what is good way?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DepartmentDto>> GetAllDepartments()
{
    var departments = await departmentRepository.GetAll().ToListAsync();
    Paged<Department> departmentPaged = new Paged<Department>(departments.AsQueryable());
    var departments2 = departmentPaged.GetPage(1, 3);
    var departmentDto = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Department>, IEnumerable<DepartmentDto>>(departments2);
    return  departmentDto;
    }
```

Was researching this also: [IQueryable does not contain definition for GetAwaiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978098/iqueryable-does-not-contain-definition-for-getawaiter)

**Other Reference Code:**

Base Repository and other options(architect at company wants generic repository, not my call):

```
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return All;
    }
    public List<T> GetAllList()
    {
        return All.ToList();
    }

    public List<T> GetAllList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return All.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> GetAllListAsync()
    {
        return await All.ToListAsync();
    }
```

**Paging Method:**

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetPage(int index, int limit)
    {
        return source.Skip((index - 1) * limit)
            .Take(limit);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have any asynchronous code in your method at all, can you clarify which bits are actually async in there?

Comment: hi @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the API, calls this App Service Method, which then calls a base data repository, not sure either, company recommended using async, in API calls down to data layer

Comment: And your option to convert it first to a list, and then back to a queryable, will remove all performance benefits of using paging, you will first grab all the items, and then paging will select only those relevant for the page. If you keep it as a queryable the whole way, paging will add criteria to the queryable to only grab the items it needs.

Comment: You need your repository to supply async operations too. Then just use the repository's async calls.

Comment: hi @LasseVågsætherKarlsen what do you recommend, remove the async? thanks

Comment: hi @Mark my base repository has other options also, just added

Comment: The implementation you posted is just as bad, I'd keep it as `IQueryable` if you're doing paging. `ToListAsync` will grab all items, without paging, then you page on the list. Paging on IQueryable will modify the query before executing it, which is likely going to be cheaper.

Comment: hi @LasseVågsætherKarlsen so do I go with the first method, and just remove Async before the task? What is the ideal ideal way to conduct this? thanks

Comment: The ideal way would be to implement proper async handling in the repository, and then use it. The way it is now you have a bad implementation of async so I'd keep your method as sync. There is not going to be any benefit from turning your method to async with your current implementation.

Comment: hi @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I have some async methods in base repository, just posted updated question, not sure if it helps,

Comment: You should check what IQueryable, ToListAsync() (in the context of EF) and all this stuff do before considering any Implementation. After you understand what each type and method does then and only then you should decide if your Implementation should be sync or async. Because right now if you live the code as is or with the code from the answer you might see some unexpected behaviour like loading all Departments into Memory before paging (which could be bad depending on the amount of Sql Entries).

Comment: Side note, why don't you use [PagedList](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I srsly think that exposing `IQueryable<T>` in a generic repository interface is a total failure, I see that you cant go against this.

Seems like you could rewrite that into:

```
public IEnumerable<DepartmentDto> GetAllDepartments()
{
    var departmentPaged = new Paged<Department>(departmentRepository.GetAll());
    return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Department>, IEnumerable<DepartmentDto>>(departmentPaged.GetPage(1, 3));
}
```

**There is no async code involved in this.**

If you still want to **force the return type to be wrapped in a task**, you can do:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<DepartmentDto>> GetAllDepartments()
{
    var departmentPaged = new Paged<Department>(departmentRepository.GetAll());
    return Task.FromResult(mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Department>, IEnumerable<DepartmentDto>>(departmentPaged.GetPage(1, 3)));
}
```

Comment: hi @JotaToledo, I have other Base Repository options besides async, let me know if it changes the answer, thanks !

Comment: by the way, I heard task fromresult is not best practice, not sure if true or not, out of these two options, which one do you prefer anyway?

Comment: Task.FromResult must be used when you are implementing a contract, such as an overridden method or an interface method, that dictates a `Task<T>` return type, but you actually have a sync implementation. Otherwise, it is not a good idea.

Comment: I would discard the 2nd option; the reasoning is as simple as the fact that you arent implementing a contract that "binds" you to that interface, so you have no reason to force the returning of a task as your method performs no async stuff.

Comment: what is the ideal way to make it async, if I scrap some code, should I add something to base repository? or sync is fine? Thanks

Comment: Sync is fine. Again, the repository interface allows an implementation of your method in a sync. manner. Why force it to be async?

Comment: hi JotaToledo, gave points and accepted answer, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks !